# How do I alert the result in this case statement?

Tags: javascript

i realize it has something to do with the case thing how do i fix or could you suggest a better way to get the final product that i want any help would be nice

```
function main()

{

    var a;
    var answer;
    a = prompt("Test Score One Out of 20", a);
    var b;
    b = prompt("Test Score Two Out of 20", b);
    var c;
    c = prompt("Test Score Three Out of 20", c);
    answer = parseInt(a,10) + parseInt(b,10) + parseInt(c,10);
    switch(answer)
    {
        case "answer >= 52":
            alert("You got an A");
            break;
        case "answer >= 42":
            alert("You got a B");
            break;
        case "answer >= 33":
            alert("You got a C");
            break;
        case "answer <= 32":
            alert("You got a D");
            break;


        default:
            alert("Failed");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's this strange case condition ? Simply use some `if`.

Comment: That's a really bad question title.

Comment: You are comparing strings to an integer in your switch statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this strange `switch` block, simply use

```
if (answer >= 52) {
   alert("You got an A");
} else if (answer >= 42) {
   alert("You got a B");
} else if ...
```

There are many other ways to do it, for example an array storing the thresholds, but this one works and is simple.